# React js compile error

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, but I am stuck with this error since last week. 
somebody help me, please!
Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! althaqalyn@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the althaqalyn@0.1.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
>   ging output above.

Comment: can you show us the full stacktrace?

Comment: this is the full error. >Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! althaqalyn@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the althaqalyn@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log ging output above.

Comment: this is the full error. >Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! althaqalyn@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the althaqalyn@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log ging output above.

Comment: please provide the code access to make it easy to debug @IbrahimNayaya

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is my debug.log

I loaded nodemon and started the server using 'nodemon' instead of npm start. It looked like there were ambiguous start scripts. I don't know if this is a fix, but I was able to continue working, so that's a win in my book!

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~prestart: bookworm-react@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: bookworm-react@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: PATH: /Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/gb/Sites/TUTORIALS/REM/bookworm/bookworm-react/node_modules/.bin:/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/gb/Sites/TUTORIALS/REM/bookworm/bookworm-react
10 silly lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bookworm-react@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: bookworm-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid bookworm-react@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/gb/Sites/TUTORIALS/REM/bookworm/bookworm-react
16 verbose Darwin 15.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/gb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.4.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bookworm-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bookworm-react@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: what do you mean with nodemon

Answer (score 1):

What I see from the given issue is that react-script is unable to install from package.json file, if you are trying to install all the dependencies. You can try to run below commands to install the dependencies and verify them.

npm install react-scripts --save

npm audit fix